# On my Galaxy Tab 2 (7.0), I am suddenly unable to connect to Wifi

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

I've googled this and turned up a bunch of inconclusive forum threads. I've also checked out a few similar questions on this site, but none of them quite match my details. So here they are:

I have a Galaxy Tab 2 (7.0) that's been working fine with my wifi router since I got it about 6 months ago. This morning when I fired it up, it rebooted and now I cannot connect to my wifi router. My wifi is not the issue as my Nexus 7 tablet is connected and working.

This is what I see:

- When I go to Settings > Wi-Fi, I see my network listed. But status is stuck on `Obtaining IP address`
- After a while, status reports `Network disabled. Poor connection`

Tablet also reports that a "Software Update" is ready. Not sure if this is related to the issue. But when I try to update, I get a confirmation page and when I hit confirm button, I get message `Unable to connect network`.

I've tried the following:

- Rebooting tablet
- Forgetting and reconnecting to my network through Wi-Fi settings
- Read [this solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/40296/35024), but couldn't find Mobile Network Settings

Here's some system data from my tablet:

```
Model Number: GT-P3113
Android Version: 4.0.4
Kernel Version: 3.0.8-999349
Build Number: IMM76D.P3113UEBLH2
```

A simple solution would be appreciated. I'll post a solution if I figure it out myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in your WiFi settings, could you try pressing `menu` (or clicking the overflow dots), and selecting `Settings`.

Once done, untick the `Avoid poor WiFi networks` option, and see if it will now connect.

Also, restart the router.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Looked all over settings for the `Avoid poor WiFi networks` option, including in Advanced Wi-Fi Settings, but don't see it on my tablet.

Comment: Unplugged my router for 30 seconds, plugged back in, problem resolved.

Comment: Can you help me ? I can't find the settings button in the overflow dots, it just show up Advanced,WPS push button and WPs PIN entry,where's the settings button?

Comment: @user59582 it's the Advanced menu.